# How can i update or insert compare two fields from database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to compare either mobile or email fields exists in database it should update row else insert row

```
$ref = Ref::updateOrCreate(
  [ 
    'mobile' => $request['mobile'],
    'email' => $request['email_address']
  ],
  [
    'firstname' => $request['firstname'],
    "lastname"   => $request['lastname'],    
    "mobile"   => $request['mobile'],
    "email"   => $request['email_address'],
    "mobile_verified"   => $req->session()->get('mobile_verified'),
    "quiz_data"   => $req->session()->get('quiz_data'),
    "verification_token"   => $req_token
  ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
$result= DB::statement("INSERT INTO table_name 
       (firstname,lastname,mobile,email,mobile_verified,quiz_data,verification_token)
       VALUES ('".$request['firstname']."','".$request['lastname']."','".$request['mobile']."','"
       .$request['email_address']."','".$req->session()->get('mobile_verified')."','"
       .$req->session()->get('quiz_data')."','".$req_token."',)
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mobile = VALUES(mobile),email = VALUES(email);");
```

Replace `table_name` with your table name and try .
Here your `mobile` and `email` will be updated if the data is present before.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Laravel function to compare on either field, you will have to execute two queries manually.

```
// Find an existing Ref
$ref = Ref::where('mobile', $request['mobile'])
    ->orWhere('email', $request['email_address'])
    ->first();

// Test if exists
if (isset($ref))
{
    $ref->update([
        // Update fields
    ]);
}
else
{
    $ref = Ref::create([
        // Create fields
    ]);
}
```